# jquery hint not working with textarea

Tags: jquery, html, forms

my jquery hint only works if in an textbox and not a a textarea. How to I make it work for both.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Shows the title in the text box, and removes it when modifying it
$('input[title]').each(function(i) {
if(!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');
}
```

only works on:

```
<input type="text" name="name" title="Full Name" >
```

but not on:

```
<textarea title="Enter Message Here"name="message" rows=8 cols=30 </textarea>
```

Comment: I don't know if it works but you can do eventually: $('input[title], textarea[title]') otherwise you run the function twice, one for $('input[title]') and one for $('textarea[title]')

Comment: That's because a text area is a `textarea` element and not an `input` element.  See answer by @nnnnnnn below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current selector, `$('input[title]')` says to select inputs with a title attribute set. It doesn't say anything about textareas.

You need to do this:

```
$('input[title],textarea[title]')
```

Or, arguably better:

```
$(':input[title]')   // note the colon
```

The first says to select all input elements with a title attribute and all textarea elements with a title attribute. The second uses jQuery's [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which automatically grabs all input, textarea, select and button elements (i.e., all form elements), but in this case restricted to those with a title attribute.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qMLRK/

NOTE: you should allow for spaces in the fields because `<textarea> </textarea>` is *not* empty:

```
if ($.trim($(this).val()) === "")

// NOT

if(!$(this).val())
```

Comment: I think you'll find both selectors work fine but you're not getting the desired effect due to other problems in your code. Even in your question you don't show a complete document.ready function and the html for the textarea has a typo (missing `>` on the opening tag). If there is a space in your textarea your current code will not consider it empty, so try updating to use `$.trim()` as shown in my updated answer and sample fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does everything as a selection.

The textarea is not a input type, so just append your JQuery selection.

```
$('input[title],textarea[title]').each(function(i) {
```

This should resolve that issue. You could also give both the same class:), then just select by the class and that will reduce your selection to just (assuming you used the name textbox as the class)

$('.textbox').each